# Iframe text doesnt appear

Tags: html, css

I have this code snippet but it's not working, the text is not showing inside the iframe.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  border: grey solid 1px;
}

p.para1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
iframe.sidepanels1 {
  border: 5px dotted green;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 550px;
  text-align: center;
}
iframe.sidepanels2 {
  border: 5px dotted green;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 550px;
}
p.iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css">
    <body>
      <center><p class="para1">This is a lot of shit to be written here<br> and this is just an example of this shit m8</p></center>
      <iframe class="sidepanels1"><p class="iframe">Testing</p></iframe>
      <iframe class="sidepanels2"><p class="iframe">Trying</p></iframe>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: an iframe is normally used to load an external page e.g src="page.htm" if you want to put text into the space occupied by your iframes, you would be better changing them to div tags

Comment: Did you really just put `<body>` inside `<head>`?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use `iframe`?

`iframe` is used to embedding another HTML page into the current page. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Change `iframe` for `div` and it will work.

```css
body {
    background-color: grey;
    border: grey solid 1px;
}

p.para1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
div.sidepanels1 {
    border: 5px dotted green;
    background-color: grey;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 550px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.sidepanels2 {
    border: 5px dotted green;
    background-color: grey;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 550px;
}
p.iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<center><p class="para1">This is a lot of shit to be written here<br> and this is just an example of this shit m8</p></center>
<div class="sidepanels1"><p class="iframe">Testing</p></div>
<div class="sidepanels2"><p class="iframe">Trying</p></div>
```

Also you cannot have the `body` inside the `head`.

You have to check the [HTML basic structure](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/html5-page-structure/) and the [tags meanings](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/), .

Answer (score 0):

You can add the HTML code you want to appear in the iframe as srcdoc
attribute.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  border: grey solid 1px;
}

p.para1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
iframe.sidepanels1 {
  border: 5px dotted green;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 550px;
  text-align: center;
}
iframe.sidepanels2 {
  border: 5px dotted green;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 550px;
}
p.iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
    <body>
      <center><p class="para1">This is a lot of shit to be written here<br> and this is just an example of this shit m8</p></center>
      <iframe class="sidepanels1" srcdoc="fsfsfsfsaf"></iframe>
      <iframe class="sidepanels2" srcdoc="safsdfsdfsf"></iframe>
    </body> 
</html>
```